# Neo4j: MERGE creates duplicate nodes

Tags: merge, neo4j, cypher

My database model has users and MAC addresses. A user can have multiple MAC addresses, but a MAC can only belong to one user. If some user sets his MAC and that MAC is already linked to another user, the existing relationship is removed and a new relationship is created between the new owner and that MAC. In other words, a MAC moves between users.

This is a particular instance of the Cypher query I'm using to assign MAC addresses:

```
MATCH (new:User { Id: 2 })
MERGE (mac:MacAddress { Value: "D857EFEF1CF6" })
WITH new, mac
OPTIONAL MATCH ()-[oldr:MAC_ADDRESS]->(mac)
DELETE oldr
MERGE (new)-[:MAC_ADDRESS]->(mac)
```

The query runs fine in my tests, but in production, for some strange reason it *sometimes* creates duplicate `MacAddress` nodes (and a new relationship between the user and each of those nodes). That is, a particular user can have multiple `MacAddress` nodes with the same `Value`.

I can tell they are different nodes because they have different node ID's. I'm also sure the `Value`s are exactly the same because I can do a `collect(distinct mac.Value)` on them and the result is a collection with one element. The query above is the only one in the code that creates `MacAddress` nodes.

I'm using Neo4j 2.1.2. What's going on here?

Thanks,
Jan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the response I got back from Neo4j's support (emphasis mine):

> I got some feedback from our team already, and it's currently known that **this can happen in the absence of a constraint**. MERGE is effectively MATCH or CREATE - and those two steps are run independently within the transaction. Given concurrent execution, and the "read committed" isolation level, there's a race condition between the two.
>
> The team have done some discussion on how to provided a higher guarantee in the face of concurrency, and do have it noted as a feature request for consideration.
>
> Meanwhile, they've assured me that **using a constraint will provide the uniqueness** you're looking for.

Answer (score 7):

Are you sure this is the entirety of the queries you're running?   `MERGE` has this really common pitfall where it merges everything that you give it.   So here's what people expect:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ MERGE (mac:MacAddress { Value: "D857EFEF1CF6" });
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes created: 1
Properties set: 1
Labels added: 1
1650 ms
neo4j-sh (?)$ MERGE (mac:MacAddress { Value: "D857EFEF1CF6" });
+--------------------------------------------+
| No data returned, and nothing was changed. |
+--------------------------------------------+
17 ms
neo4j-sh (?)$ match (mac:MacAddress { Value: "D857EFEF1CF6" }) return count(mac);
+------------+
| count(mac) |
+------------+
| 1          |
+------------+
1 row
200 ms
```

So far, so good.  That's what we expect.  Now watch this:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ MERGE (mac:MacAddress { Value: "D857EFEF1CF6" })-[r:foo]->(b:SomeNode {label: "Foo!"});
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes created: 2
Relationships created: 1
Properties set: 2
Labels added: 2
178 ms
neo4j-sh (?)$ match (mac:MacAddress { Value: "D857EFEF1CF6" }) return count(mac);                    
+------------+
| count(mac) |
+------------+
| 2          |
+------------+
1 row
2 ms
```

Wait, WTF happened here?   We specified only the same MAC address again, why is a duplicate created?

The [documentation on MERGE](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-merge.html#_introduction_4) specifies that "MERGE will not partially use existing patterns — it’s all or nothing. If partial matches are needed, this can be accomplished by splitting a pattern up into multiple MERGE clauses".  So because when we run this path `MERGE` the whole path doesn't already exist, it creates everything in it, including a duplicate mac address node.

There are frequently questions about duplicated nodes created by `MERGE`, and 99 times out of 100, this is what's going on.

Comment: I know that MERGE either fully matches, or it doesn't. It is what it is: a MERGE of a node with a `MacAddress` label and a `Value` property. I have two `MacAddress` nodes with the exact same `Value`.